# How to add multiple marker symbols to python plot?

Tags: python, plot, markers

I'm doing a cluster scatter plot where I have clusters and I'd like each cluster to be marked with a different symbol. For example, one cluster to be X another to be O and maybe a third to be `^`. I can do this with colors using :

```
colormap = np.array(['red', 'lime', 'black', 'green'])

plt.scatter(temp[2200:5000].tempvar1, temp[2200:5000].tempvar2, c=colormap[dbscan.labels_], s=40)
```

I tried a similar process for markers. Created a marker array and send that to the scatter plot but it does not work:

```
marker=np.array(['9', '+', '.', 'x'])

plt.scatter(temp[2200:5000].tempvar1, temp[2200:5000].tempvar2, marker=marker[dbscan2.labels_], c=colormap[dbscan2.labels_], s=40)
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You would probably need to loop through marker array, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706115/how-to-use-different-marker-for-different-point-in-scatter-plot-pylab

Comment: I think this would probably be the most general solution for both colours and markers, especially convenient if you want to have different combinations of colours and markers or other properties: https://matplotlib.org/cycler/ But you still have to make a loop.