# In Python, how to plot a scatter plot with the markers in Chinese?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

If the coordinate (x,y), and its corresponding Chinese z is as following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
z = ["一", "二", "三", "四", "五"]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Then it will plot:

[image]

Please tell me how to plot its corresponding Chinese, which is the z into the scatter plot as the coordinates.

Such as:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: something along `[plt.text(a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z)]` with the correct font settings would work.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but got the error, "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'", in the code "plt.text(x,y,z)"

Comment: Even if I set the z is, "z = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")"

Comment: Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: `plt.text(x,y,z)` doesn't appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: I mean I just tried it after you taught me.

Comment: you need to scale the axes manually in case you use plt.txt **instead** of plt.scatter: `plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))` and `plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))`

Comment: Look into matplotlib.pyplot's markers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706115/how-to-use-different-marker-for-different-point-in-scatter-plot-pylab

Answer (score 0):

**From [this website](https://medium.com/@hoishing/using-chinese-characters-in-matplotlib-5c49dbb6a2f7):**

It is because the fonts used by matplotlib couldn’t decode the characters properly. To solve it, we should add the appropriate fonts and update matplotlib font cache.

1. locate the matplotlib fonts folder:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
```

this is the location of matplotlib config file, you will get something like `.../matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`

The font folder is `.../matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf` , put your `ttf` file there.

2. Get `ttf` from `ttc` file (skip if you have `ttf` file already)

For macOS, the system Chinese fonts is `'Heiti'`, which is embed in a `ttc` file (`ttc` is a collection of multiple `ttf` files). Get the system `ttc` file in `/System/Library/Fonts/STHeiti Medium.ttc` Copy this file out and convert it to `ttf`. Here is an online `ttc` converter:

```
https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack
```

3. Rebuild the Matplotlib Cache

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
```

restart your Jupyter / ipython kernel, then test if `matplotlib` can load your font or not by the `ttflist` function of the font manager

```
[f for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist if 'Heiti' in f.name]
```

change `'Heiti'` to your own font name. If you see your fonts object above. You are ready to use the new fonts.

4. Using Appropriate Fonts in Matplotlib

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = ['Heiti TC']
```

This will tell matplotlib to use the specific font as default.